# Use mmap to put content into an allocated memory region

Tags: c, mmap

I have tried to read documentation on `mmap` but I am still having a hard time understanding how to use it.

I want to take an argument from the command line and then allocate it to an executable memory region. Then I want to be able to execute from that code.

This is what I have so far:

```c
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Correct input was not provided\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char assembly_code[sizeof argv[1]];
  const char *in_value = argv[1];

  int x = sscanf(in_value, "%02hhx", assembly_code);
  if (x != 1) {
    printf("sscanf failed, exited\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  void * map;

  size_t ac_size = sizeof(assembly_code) / sizeof(assembly_code[0]);
  map = mmap(NULL, ac_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC, MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

  if (map == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf("Mapping failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  ((void (*)(void))map)();

  return 0;
}
```

This is the output/error I am getting: `Mapping failed`

I don't know if I am using `mmap` correctly. And if I am I don't believe I am executing it correctly.

For example if this file is run with an argument `e8200000004889c64831c048ffc04889c74831d2b2040f054831c0b83c0000004831ff0f05e806000000584883c008c3ebf84869210a` it should return `Hi!` and then terminate. I don't really know how to get this output after the map or how to "call/execute" a `mmap`.

Comment: What have you *tried*? What problems do you have with your attempt? What errors do you get from the system calls (if any)?

Comment: Also note that your single `sscanf` call will only read and parse the first two digits of the string in `argv[1]`. Which by the way you should *always* check if it exists, by checking `argc`. You should also compare `x != 1` to be able to handle if there's invalid input in the string.

Comment: Doing some hacking i see...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan this is just a class assignment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int x = sscanf(read, "%02hhx", assembly_code);
```

This only converts a single byte.  I don't think there is a standard library function to convert a whole string of hex bytes; you'll have to call `sscanf` in a loop, incrementing pointers within the input buffer `read` and the output buffer `assembly_code` as appropriate.

In your `mmap` call, if you don't want to map a file, you should use the flag `MAP_ANONYMOUS` instead of `MAP_SHARED`.  You should also check its return value (it returns `MAP_FAILED` on error) and report any error.  Also, the return value is in principle of type `void *` instead of `int *` (though this should make no difference on common Unix systems).

The `mmap` call (after being fixed) will return a pointer to a block of memory filled with zeros.  There is no reason for it to contain your `assembly_code`, so you'll have to copy it there, perhaps with `memcpy`.  Or you could move your loop and parse the hex bytes directly into the region allocated with `mmap`.

Your  `((void (*)(void))map)();` to transfer control to the mapped address appears to be correct, so once you have the block correctly mapped and populated, it should execute your machine code.  I haven't tried to disassemble the hex string you provided to see if it actually would do what you are expecting, but hopefully it does.

Also, `read` is not a very good name for a variable, since there is also a standard library function by that name.  Your code will work, since the local variable shadows the global object, but it would be clearer to choose another name.

Oh, and `char assembly_code[sizeof argv[1]];` isn't right.  Think carefully about what `sizeof` does and doesn't do.

Comment: I tried to update my code with your recommendations. I'm not sure how to use sscanf in a loop with this type of format. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: @lex449: Since it's for a class assignment, I'm going to let you think about it.  But focus on exactly what the call `sscanf(s, "%02hhx", p)` does: it parses two characters pointed to by `s`, and stores the resulting byte in the `char` pointed to by `p`.  Think about what `s` and `p` would need to be on each iteration of the loop to do what you want.